# How to get merged cells ( Vertically and/or horizontally) in MS word using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

Folks, I am in a deep trouble. Hoping that I would get suggestions from you all I've described the issue that I'm facing with Apache POI.

I am currently using apache poi to read the contents of MS Word documents (.docx) format. The documents contain complex table structure including merged cells and nested tables. I have to identify merged cells in the table and duplicate its value in all the cells that are part of the merged cell layout. I couldn't post an image as this is my first post.

The code written below iterates through the table contents in order to fetch values in each cell. For simplicity, I have specified only the code that needs attention.

```
XWPFDocument docxFile = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docFile));
List <IBodyElement> bodyElementList = docxFile.getBodyElements();
for(int i=0;i<bodyElementList.size();i++){
    IBodyElement bodyElement = bodyElementList.get(i);
    if(bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable){
        XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)bodyElement;
        List <XWPFTableRow> rowList = table.getRows();
        for(XWPFTableRow Row : rowList){
            List <XWPFTableCell> columnList = Row.getTableCells();
            for(XWPFTableCell column: columnList) {
                CTVMerge ctvMerge = column.getCTTc().getTcPr().getVMerge();
                CTHMerge cthMerge = column.getCTTc().getTcPr().getHMerge();
                CTDecimalNumber gridSpan = column.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If **column** is a part of a vertically merged cells group, then **column.getCTTc().getTcPr().getVMerge()** always returns an instance of **org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTVMerge**, with which I can identify the start and the end of vertically merged cells by calling **cvtMerge.getVal()**.

But, I have difficulty in identifying horizontally merged cells and its range in the table. If column is a part of horizontally merged cells, then **column.getCTTc().getTcPr().getHMerge()** always returns null.

Hence, I used **column.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan()**, which returned an instance of **org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDecimalNumber**. But, the problem here is, it returns values for both horizontally merged cells and grids (if cells are merged both horizontally and vertically). In both cases, **gridSpan.getVal()** returns only the colspan value. How to get the rowspan value? If and only if I know the rowspan, I can identify the range of a grid.

Am I using the right APIs? Is there a better way to get all these info with Apache POI? Please help me in resolving this issue.

Here below is the snippet of table XML from document.xml that I got after unziping the word document. The xml snippet below ends with table-end tag, but, it is not showing up below in the code region, not sure why!!!.

```
<w:tbl>
<w:tblPr>
    <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
    <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
    <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
</w:tblPr>
<w:tblGrid>
    <w:gridCol w:w="3116"/>
    <w:gridCol w:w="3117"/>
</w:tblGrid>
<w:tr w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidTr="00834A42">
    <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="3116" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidRDefault="00004765"/>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidRDefault="00004765">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Vertically merged cells</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidTr="00834A42">
    <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="3116" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidRDefault="00004765"/>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:vMerge/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidRDefault="00004765"/>
    </w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidTr="00973ED9">
    <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="6233" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00004765" w:rsidRDefault="00004765">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Horizontally merged c</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>ells</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:tc>
</w:tr>
```

Comment: If you create a very simple word document, with one table in it, with one vertically merged and one horizontally merged cell, then unzip the `.docx` file (it's a zip of xml files), what does the table XML look like?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Gagravarr. I created a word document with a table having 2 columns and 3 rows (vertically merged the 2nd column till the 2nd row and horizontally merged the third row). I unziped the document and got many xml files. I checked document.xml file that contains the actual contents of the file. I could not post the entire content here, as there is a limitation on the reply message size. If could tell me what needs to be checked, I will do that. Otherwise, if you want to have a look at the xml, please let me know how to post that content here.

Comment: Just edit your question and post the table XML snippet into there. Indent it with 4 spaces, and it'll show up nicely in a code block

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr, please check my question edited with the table xml from document.xml.

Comment: Your horizontal ones seem to have a `w:gridSpan` in the first cell with a param of how many, the vertical one has a `w:vMerge` in the subsequent cell. Can you fetch those values to check for them?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have mentioned the same in my question that I am using those properties to identify vertical/horizontal merges. But the problem is, `w:gridSpan` will give only colspan value. If I have cells that are merged both horizontally and vertically to form a grid (for example, 2*2 grid within a table is merged), I would need rowspan value to duplicate the correct value. Please provide your input for this.

Comment: I didn't write the file format, you'd have to pop over to Redmond, Washington State if you want to have a proper rant with someone about the sanity of the way Word encodes the information... You can hopefully now see how Word does save it, can you not write some logic to detect this case?